# Node.JS V12 Trello API How to check to see if a card is overdue

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, trello

I am using Node.js V12 with the the `trello-node-api` package installed. I am able to find all the cards in a list but when I was looking through the json API for the card [Link Here](https://trello.com/c/DQmWS2Zu/2-sample-card-2.json) I am not able to find the correct title to check to see if the card is over due. I can find if the date was completed but not when the date turns red (Which is what I want) .  I am very new with Javascript and I am not sure how to check for the red due date.

**Pretty much to sum it up:** I dont know how to check to see if a card is over due or not.

Here is the code that I came up with so far

````js
Const trelloNode = require("trello-node-api")("privateinfo")


 trelloNode.board.searchCards(boardID).then(function(response) {
            response.forEach(element => {
                if (element.idList === myListId2) {
                    var cardLink = element.shortLink;
                    if () {
                     //if the card shows the "red due date"
    
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I basiclly awnsered my own question.

What I did is added two if statements.
The first one is checking to see if the card even has a due date. The second one is checking the current time against the due date. As I am new to javascript, this may not be the best way but this is my way.

```
var date1 = element.due;
var date4 = new Date("1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z") // Reason is because cards that have no due date go back to this date so I have to exclude it. 
var date2 = new Date(date1);
var date3 = new Date();
                    
if (date2.getTime() != date4.getTime()){ // Checking to see if a card has a due date
    if (date2.getTime() <= date3.getTime()){ // Checking for over due's
```